# Sendgrid v3: "Substitutions may not be used with dynamic templating"

Tags: java, maven, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to update my API Code from Sendgrid v2, to the actual Sendgrid v3, so my code used to look like this:

```
public void sendCreatedUserEmail(User user) {
    Email from = new Email(FROM);
    from.setName(EMAIL_NAME);
    String subject = "Hello" + user.getName();
    Email to = new Email(user.getEmail());
    Content content = new Content("text/html", "Something");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
    mail.personalization.get(0).addSubstitution("{name1}", user.getName());
    mail.personalization.get(0).addSubstitution("{name2}", user.getName());
    mail.setTemplateId(USER_TEMPLATE_ID);
    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    Request request = new Request();
    try {
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        Response response = sg.api(request);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
    }
}
```

After some hours of research I changed for v3 to this:
(I separeted everthing for a cleaner view)

```
public void sendCreatedUserEmail(User user) {
    Mail mail = new Mail();

    Email from = new Email();
    from.setName(EMAIL_NAME);
    from.setEmail(FROM);
    mail.setFrom(from);

    String subject = "Hello, " + user.getName();
    mail.setSubject(subject);

    Personalization personalization = new Personalization();

    Email to = new Email();
    to.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    to.setName(user.getName());
    personalization.addTo(to);

    personalization.setSubject(subject);

    personalization.addSubstitution("{name2}",user.getName());
    personalization.addSubstitution("{name1}",user.getName());

    mail.addPersonalization(personalization);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.setType("text/html");
    content.setValue("Something");
    mail.addContent(content);

    mail.setTemplateId(NEW_USER_TEMPLATE_ID);

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    Request request = new Request();
    try {
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        Response response = sg.api(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

ERROR ROOT - java.io.IOException: Request returned status Code 400Body:{"errors":[{"message":"Substitutions may not be used with dynamic templating","field":"personalizations.0.substitutions","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.personalizations.substitutions"}]}

And I really don't know how to proceed! I've been reading the sendgrid documentation but I couldn't get it.

Some details that might help
 - Java8 is the language
 - MAVEN for dependencies
 - IntelliJ for the IDE

Sorry for the possible mistakes, it's my first post and English is not my main language. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

V3 of the Sendgrid API uses Dynamic Template Data instead of substitutions.

Try this instead of using `addSubstitution`:

```
personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("{name2}",user.getName());
personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("{name1}",user.getName());
```

Sources:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/9bc569cbdb908dba609ed0d9d2691dff319ce155/src/main/java/com/sendgrid/helpers/mail/objects/Personalization.java

https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need the curly braces around the variable names - in fact it didn't work for me with those included. This worked:
personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("name2",user.getName());

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("name2",user.getName());
personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("name1",user.getName());
```